# Laravel query screws my variables

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, laravel

**Controller:**

```
public function getSpecificPost($id)
{
    $returnArray = with(new Posts)->getSpecificPost($id);

    print_r($returnArray);
}
?>
```

**Model:**

```
public function getSpecificPost($post_id)
{
   //exit($post_id);
   return DB::table('posts')->where('id', $post_id)->toSql();
}
?>
```

If I uncomment the exit, it gives me a 1 as return.
When I comment the exit I of course get a query, the query is as follows:

`select * from`posts`where`id`= ?`

Its Laravel Framework, help me out please!

Comment: What's your actual question please?

Comment: @Markus
When I do this I get an error.
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `1` from `posts`)

@Phil, whats going wrong here, why isn't it showing the ID i'm passing?

Comment: @Markus403 that isn't right. If you add params in the `select`, you are selecting that column. This, however, will work: `return DB::table('posts')->where('id', $post_id)->get();`

Comment: Yes sorry for my misleading comment. Going to delete it. However the best for Chilion would be to just take a look at the laravel documentation to see what to use for his special need: [see here](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` is a placeholder for your variable. It will be replaced with (in this case) `1`. See the colored block on [this page](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#Introduction):

> Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout
>   to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no
>   need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

You are aware of the fact that your don't actually execute the query? If you want to get the specific `post` with `$post_id`, you can change the line in your model to this one:

```
return DB::table('posts')->where('id', $post_id)->first();
```

If you want to see all executed queries (with replaced variables!) with Eloquent, you can use [Laravel PHP Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of that. Now when I put it in the way you did it works. As I said, I must be retarded. Ah, my question is altered. To friendly :)

Comment: You know why I used `first()` instead of `get()`? Maybe it's an idea you take a look at the [Eloquent documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) for more information. Good luck :)

Comment: I THINK it's like LIMIT 1; But will, check the docxxx. Tnx for your answer!